# Are the white dots mould or part of the bread?

Tags: bread

The bread is called Malted bread, 9/10 I see this I believe it’s mould but does anyone actually know if it’s actually part of the bread or not? Top right corner.

Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 5):

Malting is when a grain is sprouted then dried.  Often it is then ground, or in the case of some well known and often appreciated drinks fermented. In your picture, I see malted grain kernels in the upper right.  Completely normal for a malted bread if whole grains rather than ground is used for some of the malted portion.